# Why is this not to use GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I installed nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver.
I got nvcc -V

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Jan__9_17:32:33_CST_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.60

But tensoflow is

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

2023-02-20 17:16:03.556026: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1850] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 16176753119491980911
xla_global_id: -1
]

In pytorch, I got
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
True

How to use GPU in Tensoflow.
Tensoflow version is 2.7.0 and tensoflow-gpu.

I did Windows set up.

Comment: Did you "make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU" and "Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

prints your GPU.

Once your GPU also gets listed, you may need to switch it between CPU or GPU. CPU is usually `CPU/0` which can be found out with `tf.device()` . Try running this code

```
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
# Place tensors on the CPU
with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
  a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
  b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
# Run on the GPU
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
print(c)
```

Are you running it in Windows, LINUX or COLLAB?

Comment: I did this, But I can't use GPU.
Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU.

Comment: I installed tensoflo-gpu == 2.7.0 and Cuda 11.1.0.

Comment: Can I get to know what's your graphic card?you may need to install graphics card driver,followed by directx(not fully required) and then cuda which you have installed.Make sure you have enabled your graphics card from its control panel.

Comment: There are additional things required for it to work correctly which is listed here [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native_1). Also suggested by mrmyagi

Comment: You need msvcp140_1.dll installed from Microsoft visual code library.